# Outcome of Function - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, python-3.x

I'm creating a utility program whose functions will be used as part of another program.

This is my function (EDITED):

```
def push_up (grid):
   new_grid = up_down_swapper(grid)


   new_grid = zero_DR(new_grid) 

   for i in range(4):
     for j in range(3):                
        if new_grid[i][j] == new_grid[i][j+1]:
            new_grid[i][j+1] = (new_grid[i][j])+(new_grid[i][j])
            new_grid[i][j] = 0
        else: 
            pass

new_grid = zero_DR(new_grid)

grid = up_down_swapper(new_grid)
#print(grid) - shows the grid as the expected outcome. But outside of the function it  doesn't change
```

and here is how it's used:

```
push.push_up (grid)
```

As you guys can see it isn't being assigned to a value like

```
new_grid = push.push_up (grid)
```

I cannot change the main program ( this is an assignment and  this is what I've been told to do.)

My problem is how do I get the function to change the value of the parameter? I'm not sure if I'm making sense but something like this:

```
def square(x):
    x = x*x

value = 3 
square(value) 
print(value)
```

This will output 3, but I'm wanting 9. How would I go about doing this?

Here is a pastebin of the main code:
http://pastebin.com/NAxWL14h

Comment: ...you do appear to be modifying `grid` in-place. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I think this is a scope problem. See related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-question

Comment: my problem is that "grid" isn't changing outside of the function. I have edited the question to show the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that because of how Python passes parameters, you can't do this. For your `square` example, there is no way to change the value of `value` without assigning the result of `square(value)` to it.

However, you don't need to change what `grid` is pointing to. In part of your code

```
for i in range(4): #add numbers that are equal  
    for j in range(3,-1,-1):                
        if grid[i][j] == grid[i][j-1]:
            grid[i][j-1] = (grid[i][j])+(grid[i][j])
            grid[i][j] = 0
        else: 
            pass
```

You are changing the values held within `grid`. So think about it this way:

```
>>> list_to_add_to = []
>>> def add_to_list(a_list):
...     a_list.append('test')
...
>>> print(list_to_add_to)
[]
>>> add_to_list(list_to_add_to)
>>> print(list_to_add_to)
['test']
```

I did not change what `list_to_add_to` refers to, but I was still able to modify it. This is referred to as "modifying in-place".

So instead of trying to create a new `grid` and return that result, you have two options:

1. Modify the contents of `grid`
2. Create a new `grid` (calling it something else like `new_grid`) and work with that. Then at the end of your function, copy everything from `new_grid` into `grid`.

Comment: I have attempted both options but I'm not getting a change in the "grid" outside of the function. I've shown this in the Original Post

Comment: @Itachi Saying `grid = up_down_swapper(new_grid)` does not copy anything into `grid`. `grid[i][j] = new_grid[i][j]` does.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between

- having a name refer to a different value / object and
- modifying the object a name refers to.

The first one is done with an assignment:

```
a = []
b = a
b = [3]
print(a) # still prints []
```

The second one is only possible with mutable objects (e. g., lists are ok, tuples not):

```
a = []
b = a
b.append(3)
print(a) # prints [3]
```

When you do a function call, you essentially do the same:

```
def f(b):
    b = [3]
```

only changes what `b` points to inside the function.

However,

```
def g(b):
    b.append(3)
```

changes the `list` object provided by the caller.

Exactly this is the point: the function in your assignment should modify `grid` in-place. Instead, you assign it a different object, which won't propagate back to the caller.

Comment: How would I go about modifying grid in-place?

Comment: @Itachi Either by assigning to certain index positions, such as `grid[i][j] = 123`, as you already do, or by e. g. `grid.append(123)` to increase the size. As soon as you do `new_grid = some_operation(grid)`, the connection to the "original one" is lost.